How can I use XStream to start parsing from a given XML Path
I have an XML file with the following shape:
<file>
  <items>
    <item name="item1">
      <labels>
        <label code="item 2 label 1" />
      </labels>
    </item>
  </items>
  <labels>
    <label code="label 3"/>
    <label code="label 3"/>
    <label code="label 3"/>
  </labels>
</file>

I would like to parse the labels elements under /file/labels/
What I tried:
@Bean
public XStreamMarshaller marshaller() {
  XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();

  marshaller.setAliases(Map.of(
    "label", Label.class
  ));

  marshaller.setTypePermissions(new ExplicitTypePermission(new Class[] {
      Label.class
  }));

  return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public StaxEventItemReader<Label> labelItemReader() {
  return new StaxEventItemReaderBuilder<Label>()
      .name("labelItemReader")
      .resource(new ClassPathResource("file.xml"))
      .addFragmentRootElements("label")
      .unmarshaller(marshaller())
      .build();
}

This will actually work but I will get all the label elements from the file including the unwanted labels under /file/items/item/label
I would like to start my parsing at /file/labels/

Make sure you only parse  elements under /file/labels/ and skip others, you can use a custom XML event reader to filter the elements based on their position in the XML structure.
i created a Custom Event Reader to track the depth of XML elements to know when you are inside /file/labels/ and ignore others.
public class CustomLabelEventReader extends FragmentEventReader {
private boolean insideTargetLabels = false;
private int depth = 0;

@Override
public XMLEvent nextEvent() throws XMLStreamException {
    XMLEvent event = super.nextEvent();
    if (event.isStartElement() && 
    event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("labels") && 
    depth == 1) {
        insideTargetLabels = true;
    }
    if (event.isEndElement() && 
    event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("labels") && 
    depth == 2) {
        insideTargetLabels = false;
    }
    depth += event.isStartElement() ? 1 : event.isEndElement() ? -1 : 0;
    return insideTargetLabels || event.isEndElement() ? event : nextEvent();
}

}
and use it in StaxEventItemReader:
  @Bean
  public StaxEventItemReader<Label> labelItemReader() {
  return new StaxEventItemReaderBuilder<Label>()
    .name("labelItemReader")
    .resource(new ClassPathResource("file.xml"))
    .xmlEventReaderFactory(() -> new 
  CustomLabelEventReader(createXmlEventReader()))
    .fragmentRootElementName("label")
    .unmarshaller(marshaller())
    .build();

}

Hello @gdoura-mohamed thanks for your answer and it looks good but unfortunately I am not able to reproduce it because FragmentEventReader is a interface and an interface cannot be "Extended". I'm using spring-batch 5.1.2.
